# read csv files and perform function, then bind together

Tags: r, function, csv, rbind

I have multiple CSV files and I know how to read them and rbind them. But my problem is that before binding them, I want to perform some actions, and then rbind them.

So for one file i would do this:

```
a<-read.table(file="F:..... .csv", skip=1401, nrow=2,header=FALSE, sep=";")
head(a)
##display only some columns
G<-a[,c(11:13)]
H<-a[, c(14:16)]
names(G)<-names(H)
H_G<-as.data.frame(rbind(G, H))
##transpose to long format
H_G<-t(H_G)
```

and now i want to rbind fromm all other files.

I tried it with this

```
filenames <- list.files(path="F:....2",pattern="*.csv")
readlist <- lapply(filenames, read.table, skip=1401, nrow=2,header=FALSE, sep=";")
```

but then I do not get the result I want.

Comment: untested but perhaps helpful `lapply(filenames, function(x) read.table(x, skip=1401, nrow=2,header=FALSE, sep=";")))`

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you want

Here I initialize some test matrices:

```
a<-matrix(1:100,10)
b<-matrix(901:1000,10)
write.csv(file="test.csv",a)
write.csv(file="test2.csv",b)
```

Here I perform your loop:

```
filenames <- dir(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in c(1:length(filenames))){  
  print(filenames[i])
  assign(filenames[i],read.csv(filenames[i], header=FALSE))
  assign(filenames[i], get(filenames[i])[,8:10])
  if(i==1){output<-data.frame(matrix(vector(),10,0))}
  results<-rbind(output,get(filenames[i]))
  if(i==length(filenames)){output<-t(results)}
}
```

Notes: column numbers I did in this line  `assign(filenames[i], get(filenames[i])[,8:10])` are arbitrary, you should insert your own.

Let me know if you have any questions or if this doesn't work for you.
`